# How to deploy Ionic App live in browser via Heroku

Tags: cordova, heroku, ionic-framework, deployment

I created an Ionic App and now I like to showcase it on my portfolio site. I know its possible to run the app in an iPhone frame in the browser like so https://ionic-stage.herokuapp.com/stage/?app=catalogue.

From the link I gathered that I have to deploy my app to Heroku. But my main question is how to get it in the iPhone frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually pretty easy to do this. All you have to do is copy the contents of your `www` folder to heroku. Then you have to make a file (for example) `mobile.html` in this same folder to where you copied the contents of the Ionic `www` folder, with the following contents:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
</head>
<body style="text-align:center;">
    <img src="img/iphone6.png" style="  position: absolute; top: 50px; left: 20px;" />
    <iframe src="index.html" style="  position: absolute; top: 150px; left: 48px; width: 341px; height: 606px; border: none;"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Of course, you can style it as you wish, I only copied my example that I use at: http://nikola-dev.com/IonicCalculator/mobile.html.

So, two important things here:

- the  `img` tag, where you'll place your phone image
- the `iframe` tag where you load your app (if you haven't changed anything in your Ionic app that will be `index.html`).

Hope this helps.